# Make a program in path preferable instead of another

Tags: linux, unix, path

There is a program in the PATH variable installed by root, but I installed a more recent version in my local.

There is any way to make my program preferable instead of the root?

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the preferred directory in front of the other one.  It will pick up the first one it finds.

```
export PATH=/this/path/is/searched/first:/this/one/is/second:$PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

```
export PATH="/path/to/my/local/directory:$PATH"
```

Set this in your shell's startup file (e.g., ~/.bash_profile or ~/.zshenv) and restart your shell (or just execute it in your terminal).